# Marshalling nested custom Objects in Sangria

Tags: scala, playframework, sangria

I have the following Input Objects:

```
val BusinessInputType = InputObjectType[BusinessInput]("BusinessInput", List(
    InputField("userId", StringType),
    InputField("name", StringType),
    InputField("address", OptionInputType(StringType)),
    InputField("phonenumber", OptionInputType(StringType)),
    InputField("email", OptionInputType(StringType)),
    InputField("hours", ListInputType(BusinessHoursInputType))

  ))


 val BusinessHoursInputType = InputObjectType[BusinessHoursInput]("hours",  List(
    InputField("weekDay", IntType),
    InputField("startTime", StringType),
    InputField("endTime", StringType)
  ))
```

And here are my models with custom Marshalling defined:

```
case class BusinessInput(userId: String, name: String, address: Option[String], phonenumber: Option[String], email: Option[String], hours: Seq[BusinessHoursInput])

object BusinessInput {

  implicit val manual = new FromInput[BusinessInput] {
    val marshaller = CoercedScalaResultMarshaller.default

    def fromResult(node: marshaller.Node) = {
      val ad = node.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]

      System.out.println(ad)
      BusinessInput(
        userId = ad("userId").asInstanceOf[String],
        name = ad("name").asInstanceOf[String],
        address = ad.get("address").flatMap(_.asInstanceOf[Option[String]]),
        phonenumber = ad.get("phonenumber").flatMap(_.asInstanceOf[Option[String]]),
        email = ad.get("email").flatMap(_.asInstanceOf[Option[String]]),
        hours = ad("hours").asInstanceOf[Seq[BusinessHoursInput]]

      )
    }
  }
}



case class BusinessHoursInput(weekDay: Int, startTime: Time, endTime: Time)

object BusinessHoursInput {

  implicit val manual = new FromInput[BusinessHoursInput] {
    val marshaller = CoercedScalaResultMarshaller.default
    def fromResult(node: marshaller.Node) = {
      val ad = node.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]
      System.out.println("HEY")

      BusinessHoursInput(
        weekDay = ad("weekDay").asInstanceOf[Int],
        startTime = Time.valueOf(ad("startTime").asInstanceOf[String]),
        endTime = Time.valueOf(ad("endTime").asInstanceOf[String])
      )
    }
  }


}
```

My question is, When I have a nested `InputObject` that has custom Marshalling, I dont see the marshalling of `BusinessHoursInput` getting invoked before the `BusinessInput` is marshalled. I noticed this because the print statement of "Hey" is never executed before the print statement of "ad" in `BusinessInput`. This causes problems later down the road for me when I try to insert the hours field of `BusinessInput` in the DB because it cannot cast it to `BusinessHoursInput` object. In Sangria, is it not possible to custom Marshal nested Objects before the parent Object is marshalled?

Answer (score 5):

You are probably are using `BusinessInput` as an argument type. The actual implicit lookup takes place at the `Argument` definition time and only for `BusinessInput` type.

Since `FromInput` is a type-class based deserialization, you need to explicitly define the dependency between deserializers of nested object. For example, you can rewrite the deserializer like this:

case class BusinessInput(userId: String, name: String, address: Option[String], phonenumber: Option[String], email: Option[String], hours: Seq[BusinessHoursInput])

```
object BusinessInput {
  implicit def manual(implicit hoursFromInput: FromInput[BusinessHoursInput]) = new FromInput[BusinessInput] {
    val marshaller = CoercedScalaResultMarshaller.default

    def fromResult(node: marshaller.Node) = {
      val ad = node.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]

      BusinessInput(
        userId = ad("userId").asInstanceOf[String],
        name = ad("name").asInstanceOf[String],
        address = ad.get("address").flatMap(_.asInstanceOf[Option[String]]),
        phonenumber = ad.get("phonenumber").flatMap(_.asInstanceOf[Option[String]]),
        email = ad.get("email").flatMap(_.asInstanceOf[Option[String]]),
        hours = hoursFromInput.fromResult(ad("hours").asInstanceOf[Seq[hoursFromInput.marshaller.Node]])
      )
    }
  }
}
```

In this version, I'm taking advantage of existing `FromInput[BusinessHoursInput]` to deserialize `BusinessHoursInput` from the raw input.

Also as an alternative, you can avoid defining manual `FromInput` deserializers altogether by taking advantage of existing JSON-based deserializers. For example, in most cases, circe's automatic derivation works just fine. You just need these 2 imports (in the file where you are defining the arguments):

```
import sangria.marshalling.circe._
import io.circe.generic.auto._
```

Those import put appropriate `FromInput` instances into the scope. These instances take advantage of circe's own deserialization mechanism.

Comment: ```hours = hoursFromInput.fromResult(ad("hours").asInstanceOf[Seq[hoursFromInput.marshaller.Node]])``` This does not seem to work. It says, ```type mismatch, expected hoursFromInput.marshaller.Node but found Seq[hoursFromInput.marshaller.Node]```. This is obvious as fromResult of BusinessHoursInput takes only Node. What am I missing ?

Comment: On exact same situation, where nested objects are not getting deserialized. @tenshi Any example to see how the nested deserializer works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import io.circe.Decoder
import io.circe.generic.semiauto.deriveDecoder
import sangria.macros.derive.deriveInputObjectType
import sangria.marshalling.circe._
import sangria.schema.{Argument, InputObjectType}


object XXX {

  // when you have FromInput for all types in case class (Int, String) you can derive it
  case class BusinessHoursInput(weekDay: Int, startTime: String, endTime: String)

  object BusinessHoursInput {
    implicit val decoder: Decoder[BusinessHoursInput] = deriveDecoder
    implicit val inputType: InputObjectType[BusinessHoursInput] = deriveInputObjectType[BusinessHoursInput]()
  }

  // the same here, you need InputObjectType also for BusinessHoursInput
  case class BusinessInput(userId: String, name: String, address: Option[String], phonenumber: Option[String], email: Option[String], hours: Seq[BusinessHoursInput])

  object BusinessInput {
    implicit val decoder: Decoder[BusinessInput] = deriveDecoder
    implicit val inputType: InputObjectType[BusinessInput] = deriveInputObjectType[BusinessInput]()
  }

  // for this to work you need to have in scope InputType BusinessInput and FromInput for BusinessInput
  // FromInput you can get by having Decoder in scope and import sangria.marshalling.circe._
  private val businessInputArg = Argument("businessInput", BusinessInput.inputType)


}
```

id you do not use circe but different json library you should have  of course different typeclasses and proper import in scope